# Selecting rows in a table based on same cell values in a column and looping through the table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook with 2 Sheets. One Sheet is a table that gets updated every month with invoicing information and one sheet is a preset for an invoice.

I have working VBA code that takes a (manual) selection of rows and then copies the relevant information from these rows to the preset invoice in the second sheet. This then gets automatically exported as a PDF and saved to a folder.

This code/module works flawlessly. The selection of rows is based on a transaction number that is in a column. I select (manually) all rows with the same transaction number.

Now instead of manually going through the rows and selecting the relevant rows based on a transaction number and then starting the module, I'd like to automate this process.

What I have so far:

```
Sub PrintAll()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Arr
    Dim DB As Worksheet

    Set DB = Sheets("Data")

    '~~> Set Range here
    Arr = DB.Range("A2:X400").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)

            If Arr(i, 7) = Arr(i + 1, 7) Then
                Arr(i, j).Select
                Call InvoiceCreator.InvoiceCreator
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

The idea is to select an array based on an if statement that the values in column 7 are the same and then running the module based on the selected array. This might be completely wrong so I'm asking you guys for your experience regarding this.

Comment: is your current code not working?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: several questions: How do you call your module? Which values do you want to check are equal in column 7?

Comment: The basic idea is the following: I have sets of rows with the same value in column 7. column 7 is basically a document number and all rows that have the same document number should be selected. after this selection of X rows with the same document number / value in column 7 i want to call the module: InvoiceCreator.

Comment: How does InvoiceCreator work? because you are not passing any value to it?

Comment: it takes a range and copies the values to a second sheet. if it makes it easier i can just copy the code from the InvoiceCreator here

Comment: Yes so paste it